# A job scheduling problem intending for least total loss

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, greedy, np

Suppose we have `n` jobs for scheduling and we want to find a job scheduling order to achieve least total loss. Each job has three properties: `(b,l,k)` where `b` indicates the coming time of each job, `l` indicates the time it needs for running and `k` is the coefficient. When a job is served, it **cannot be preempted**, and we just have **one** machine. The waiting time of a job is defined as  serving time – coming time​. We define the loss of a job as its waiting time times its k.

For example, we have three jobs: `(0,10,1), (2,3,5), (4,7,3)`. If we follow its initial order `1,2,3`, then the loss of each job is `0, (10-2)×5=40, (13-4)×3=27`,respectively, and the total losses is 67. However, if we follow the order `2,3,1`, we can get lower total loss `0+12+3=15`. It means, although the first job comes at time 0, we don't handle it. Instead, until we finish the third job, we choose the first job for scheduling. Here is the detailed explanation following order `2,3,1`

[image]

I think this problem shares a little bit similarity with the SJF algorithm in operating system, but also very different from each other.

Here is the main part of my thinking. Basically I come up with a **greedy algorithm**. I maintain a `deque` to keep the job that coming before but not be handled timely. When we need to choose a job for scheduling, I consider the jobs in deque and the jobs coming when a job is serving. I compare the loss between these jobs to find a job to get added loss. Well…my English is not good. If someone want to read more, please go to my [github repo](https://github.com/Zebulon-Chen/Media-Scheduling)

**I wonder whether or not there exists a dynamic programming algorithm or other Heuristic Algorithm to get a better approximate solution?**

Below is the main part of my code, written in `C++`:

```cpp
    vector<int> order;
    deque<seg> q;
    int curr_idx = 0, curr_time = 0;
    long long total_loss = 0;
    while (curr_idx < n || !q.empty()) {
        //当所有任务都已入队，直接处理队中任务
        if (curr_idx == n) {
            //计算队中所有k之和
            int k_sum = 0;
            for (auto &s : q) {
                k_sum += s.k;
            }
            while (!q.empty()) {
                //比较选择哪个任务可以带来最小的*新增*损失
                int min_loss = INT_MAX;
                deque<seg>::iterator min_it = q.begin();//换成auto也行
                for (auto it = q.begin();it != q.end();it++) {
                    int loss = it->last*(k_sum - it->k);
                    if (loss < min_loss) {
                        min_it = it;
                        min_loss = loss;
                    }
                }
                order.push_back(min_it->beg);
                total_loss += min_loss;
                curr_time += min_it->last;
                k_sum -= min_it->k;
                q.erase(min_it);
            }
            break;
        }
        //系统初始情况或者期间没有任务及时到来
        //推进当前时间，相当于指针在时间轴往前跑，直到找到一个新的任务
        //while用来将同时刻的任务全部入队
        if (q.empty()) {
            int time = segs[curr_idx].beg;
            while (curr_idx < n&&segs[curr_idx].beg == time)
                q.push_back(segs[curr_idx++]);
            curr_time = q.front().beg;
        }
        int k_sum = 0;
        for (auto &s : q) {
            k_sum += s.k;
        }
        //比较选择哪个队中任务可以带来最小的*新增*损失
        int min_loss = INT_MAX;
        deque<seg>::iterator min_it = q.begin();//换成auto也行
        int lower_idx = -1;
        bool in_queue = true;
        for (auto it = q.begin();it != q.end();it++) {
            int loss = it->last*(k_sum - it->k);//若选当前任务，当其执行完毕时的队列其他任务新增损失
            int idx = curr_idx;
            //区间内到达任务由于目前在处理it任务而造成的新增损失
            while (idx < n&&segs[idx].beg <= curr_time + it->last) {
                loss += (curr_time + it->last - segs[idx].beg)*segs[idx].k;
                idx++;
            }
            if (loss < min_loss) {
                min_loss = loss;
                min_it = it;
                in_queue = true;
            }
            //开始比较是否可以先执行在后续区间内的任务能带来更小的损失
            for (int i = curr_idx;i < n&&segs[i].beg <= curr_time + it->last;i++) {
                //队列中所有任务由于继续等待造成的新增损失
                int end_time = segs[i].beg + segs[i].last;
                int loss2 = (end_time - curr_time)*k_sum;
                for (int j = curr_idx;j < n&&segs[j].beg <= end_time;j++) {
                    if (j != i)
                        loss2 += (end_time - segs[j].beg)*segs[j].k;
                }
                if (loss2 < min_loss) {
                    min_loss = loss2;
                    in_queue = false;
                    lower_idx = i;
                }
            }
        }

        total_loss += min_loss;
        //区间内没有可以造成更小损失的任务，执行队内任务
        if (in_queue) {
            curr_time += min_it->last;
            order.push_back(min_it->beg);
            q.erase(min_it);
            while (curr_idx < n&&segs[curr_idx].beg <= curr_time) {
                q.push_back(segs[curr_idx]);
                curr_idx++;
            }
        }
        else {
            order.push_back(segs[lower_idx].beg);
            curr_time = segs[lower_idx].beg + segs[lower_idx].last;
            //将该任务前的到达任务入队，并注意跳过该任务
            while (curr_idx < n&&segs[curr_idx].beg <= curr_time) {
                if (curr_idx != lower_idx)
                    q.push_back(segs[curr_idx]);
                curr_idx++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not very clear on how you are calculating the losses in your example above. How is your coming time 0, 10 and 13 in the above examples -->  0, (10-2)×5=40, (13-4)×3=27

Comment: well, 0, 10, and 13 are time for serve instead of coming time. Because we choose `(0,10,1)` for scheduling first, the job `(2,3,5)` has to wait until the first job serve over, when the time is 10. So the second job waiting time is 10-2=8, and its loss is 8*5=40, and the third job is as the same.

Comment: how big can n be? and how big can the times be?

Comment: There is no such particular limit on it. But you may assume `n` is under `100` and `time` is under `1000`. The `n` I test for my node is under `10` because I have to use brute force to check its accuracy:)

Comment: Yeah ok still not clear how your loss is 12, 0, 7 when the order is 2, 3, 1. Can you edit your question with detailed explanation on how each job's serving time, coming time, waiting time and loss is calculated.

Comment: I am sorry for the little error in my examlpe. Now I have fixed it and added detailed explanation for order `2,3,1`.